# Unhandled error for request GET /api/Wallet/import: Error: No method exists to handle GET /Wallet/import

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I executed the command "composer-rest-server -c admin@example -a true", the website "http://localhost:3000/explorer/" show RESTAPI, but it not show "/api/wallet/"

Answer (score 0):

I modify the command as "composer-rest-server -c admin@example -a true -m true", and then "/api/wallet/" shows